# Changing a number defined in a C++(C) program without compiling the source again

Tags: c++, windows

Suppose I have this simple program which prints a number:

```
#include <iostream>
int unique_id = 112233;
int main()
{
    std::cout << unique_id;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it to something like `a.exe`. Now I want to create another application that opens `a.exe` and changes `unique_id` to something else. Is it possible?
I'm not going to pass a parameter to the program because of some restrictions.

I want to use the `unique_id`, as its name implies, to uniquely identify where my program is running. But I don't want to compile my program 1000 times for 1000 customers. I know I can use Hard Disk Serial number, but in virtual machines, this serial number may be omitted. I know I can use CPU serial number, But I read in S.O posts that this serial number is deprecated. I know I can use MAC address too :), but that address can be changed easily. So I decided to put the unique ID in exe file itself.

Comment: "Is it possible?" No.

Comment: It's possible but beyond the scope of the language.

Comment: Do not use all UPPERCASE identifiers for compile time constants, it is antipattern.

Comment: Possible if you know the structure of the compiled binary and make your program to edit this structure. Pretty fragile.

Comment: @Slava Thanks. Updated :)

Comment: @saeed this advise is not particularly for your example but for your habit, get rid of it if you do not want to meet hard to debug problems in the future.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Please motivate your question.... What is the actual constant, and what is its purpose?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Question Motivated :)

Comment: BTW, tell more about the company for which you are writing your code. I surely will avoid buying it! 1. Your question shows a basic misunderstanding about compilation, processors and operating systems. 2. Your efforts are going into useless protection schemes, to the detriment of genuine software quality (which requires a lot of efforts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you cannot change anything without re-compiling.

In practice and in very limited cases, you might patch your binary. This is mostly processor specific (and executable format specific and ABI specific) and depends less on your particular operating system version (e.g. if it works for Windows 9, it could work for Windows 10).

<sup>(However, I don't know and never used Windows; I'm only using Linux; you should adapt my answer to your operating system)</sup>

So in *some cases* you might reverse-engineer your binary executable. If you do have the C source code, you could ask your compiler to emit the assembler code (e.g. by compiling with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then you might disassemble your executable, and change, with a binary or hexadecimal editor, the machine code containing that constant.

This won't always work, because the machine instruction (and its size) could depend on the magnitude (bit size) of your constant.

To take a simple example, in C, for GCC 7, on Linux/x86-64, consider the following C file:

```
 /// A, B, C are preprocessor symbols defined as integers
 int f(int x) { 
   if (x > 0)
     return A*x + B;
   return C;
 }
```

If I compile that with `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O -DA=12751 -DB=32 -DC=11 e.c` I'm getting:

```
    .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
# e.c:3:   if (x > 0)
    testl   %edi, %edi  # x
    jle .L3 #,
# e.c:4:     return A * x + B;
    imull   $12751, %edi, %edi  #, x, tmp90
    leal    32(%rdi), %eax  #, <retval>
    ret
.L3:
# e.c:5:   return C;
    movl    $11, %eax   #, <retval>
# e.c:6: }
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   f, .-f
```

But if I do `gcc -S -O -fverbose-asm -DA=12753 -DB=32 -DC=10 e.c` I'm getting

```
    .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
# e.c:3:   if (x > 0)
    testl   %edi, %edi  # x
    jle .L3 #,
# e.c:4:     return A * x + B;
    imull   $12753, %edi, %edi  #, x, tmp90
    leal    32(%rdi), %eax  #, <retval>
    ret
.L3:
# e.c:5:   return C;
    movl    $10, %eax   #, <retval>
# e.c:6: }
    ret
```

So indeed, in the above case I could patch the binary (I would need to find the `12751` and `11`  constants in machine code; it is doable but tedious in that case).

---

Now, let's try with A being a small power of two, like 16, and C being 0, so
`gcc -S -O -fverbose-asm -DA=16 -DB=32 -DC=0 e.c`:

```
f:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
# e.c:4:     return A * x + B;
    leal    2(%rdi), %eax   #, tmp90
    sall    $4, %eax    #, tmp93
    testl   %edi, %edi  # x
    movl    $0, %edx    #, tmp92
    cmovle  %edx, %eax  # tmp93,, tmp92, <retval>
# e.c:6: }
    ret
```

Because of compiler optimizations, the code changed significantly. It is not easy to patch.

### Important notice

With enough effort, money and time (think of NSA-like abilities) a lot of things are possible.

if your goal is to obfuscate some data in your binary (e.g. some password), you might encrypt it to make hackers' life harder (but don't be naive, the NSA will be able to get it). Remember the motto: there is [***No Silver Bullet***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet); it looks that is your goal, but don't be too naive (BTW, the legal protections around your software, e.g. the license, matters even more; so you need a lawyer to write a good EULA).

If your goal is on the contrary to adapt some performance-critical code, you could use [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) and [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) techniques. A practice I like doing is generate *at runtime* some temporary C (or C++) code (better suited for your particular situation and data), compile that temporary C or C++ code as some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), then [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) that temporary plugin (using [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) on Linux; on Windows you'll need `LoadLibrary` but I leave you to understand the details and consequences). Instead of generating C or C++ code at runtime you could use some [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). If you are fond of such techniques, consider instead using better programming languages (like Common Lisp with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)) if your management allows them.

> But I don't want to compile my program 1000 times for 1000 customers

That surprises me a lot. Compiling a simple (short) C file containing just constants is quick, and linking time is also quick. I would instead consider recompilation for each customer.

BTW, I feel *you are incredibly naive*. The most important protection is not technical in your binary, it is a legal protection (and you need a good contract, so find and pay a good lawyer).

Did you consider on the contrary to make your product free software? Many companies are doing that (and making money on something else that licenses, e.g. support).

---

NB. there are lots of existing [license managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_manager). Did you consider buying and using one? Notice also that corporations have large incentives to avoid cheating, and those willing to steal your software will be able to do that anyway. You'll sell more products by working on software quality, not by spending efforts on vain "protection" measures which are annoying your customers, increasing your [logistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistics) and distribution and maintenance costs, and harden the debugging of customer-found bugs.

Comment: plus the constant might be compiled out altogether.

Comment: Not to encourage this sort of thing but if you change the line to `const volatile int unique_id = 112233` the program would load unique_id on each usage and prevent it from being optimized away. This sort of thing is common, if usually through pointers in embedded programming.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the motivation you added to the question, you could simply make the exe read the id from a .txt file, and ship a different .txt file with the exe for every customer.

Or, equivalently, you could make a DLL (or the equivalent for your platform) that has a function returning the id, and only recompile the DLL for every customer.

Answer (score 2):

No, the behaviour of changing a variable that is `const` is *undefined*. So you can't do this with standard C or C++.

Your best bet is to resort to an inline assembly solution; but note that `UNIQUE_ID` might be compiled out altogether (neither C nor C++ are *reflective* languages). In order to increase the probability of `UNIQUE_ID` being retained, remove the `const` qualifier and possibly introduce `volatile`.

Personally I'd pass `UNIQUE_ID` on the command line to your program.

Starting point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fabdxz08.aspx